# Why Can't My CSS File Be Found? (JavaFX)

Tags: css, javafx

In my FX project I've got a folder called "fxml" in my resources package, and I've got a folder called "css" in my resources package. I've got several FXML files using the "global-styles" css file without issue, but my "customer-report-view" fxml file can't find the resource.

FXML directory

[image: FXML directory]

CSS directory

[image: CSS directory]

I've linked the css files the exact same way

(top.fxml)

```
<AnchorPane id="anchorPaneTop" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="175.0" prefWidth="996.0" styleClass="header" stylesheets="@../css/global-styles.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.tbonefuel.fx.Launcher">
```

(customer-report-view.fxml)

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="screenID" prefHeight="474.0" prefWidth="997.0" stylesheets="@../css/global-styles.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.tbonefuel.fx.controller.CustomerReportController">
```

The message I get in the console when initializing the customer-report-view.fxml file. (The only file not having styles applied to it)

```
null/../css/global-styles.css
```

This is all the code used for loading the FXML files and the Template

```
  public TemplateController show(String fxml) {
    try {
        TemplateController template = (TemplateController) replaceSceneContent("master-template.fxml", fxml);
        template.setApplication(this);
        return template;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * This method sets up application to render screen
 * @param _template     fxml template file
 * @param _displayPage  contents of this page will be embed inside the template
 * @return instance of display Page Controller
 * @throws Exception
 */
private Initializable replaceSceneContent(String _template, String _displayPage) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Initializing...");
    Pane main;
    AnchorPane templatePage;
    Initializable mainController;
    // get main page
    Page mainPage = Page.getPage(_displayPage);
    main = mainPage.getPane();
    // get reference of Pane to be added to the template.
    main = (AnchorPane) main.lookup("#screenID");
    mainController = mainPage.getController();

    // get template
    templatePage = (AnchorPane) getTemplate(_template);

    // get reference of the "main" section in template i.e. where the new contents will be added
    AnchorPane origMain = (AnchorPane) templatePage.lookup("#main");

    // set contents of "mainPage" into the template
    origMain.getChildren().setAll(main.getChildren());

    // create scene
    Scene scene = new Scene(templatePage, 1024, 768);

    //set stage
    LauncherContext.getContext().getStage().setScene(scene);
    LauncherContext.getContext().getStage().sizeToScene();
    return mainController;
}

/**
 * load template
 * @param _template template file name
 * @return Pane
 * @throws IOException
 */
private AnchorPane getTemplate(String _template) throws IOException {
    AnchorPane templatePage;
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
    loader.setLocation(Launcher.class.getResource("/fxml/" + _template));
    templatePage = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
    return templatePage;
}
```

Comment: Looks like the location is not set on the FXML loader. Are you using the version of `load()` that takes an `InputStream` for some reason? (If so, don't.) Post the code where you load the FXML file(s).

Comment: Updates the main post to include all the code that deals with loading FXML files. @James_D

Comment: Aren't you calling this passing `customer-report-view.fxml` as `displayPage`? If so, what is `Page.getPage(...)` doing? (BTW, your code is really hard to read. It would be much easier if you used [standard naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java), and eliminated as many of the casts as possible.)

Comment: I took a closer look in the Page class and found that it was using the version of load that took an InputStream, I changed that and the issue is gone. It is still not loading the styles, but I think I can figure it out for myself now. Thanks @James_D